# Replace string value with variable in execl and execution stopping

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I'm building a linux like shell and I'm trying to execute external commands just like in linux with "./" in the beginning.

This is how I read the commands:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "commands/commands.h"

bool starts_with(const char *a, const char *b){
if(strncmp(a,b,strlen(b)) == 0){
    return 1;
}

return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char cmd[500];

do{
    printf("$ > ");
    fgets(cmd, 499, stdin);

    if(starts_with(cmd, "./")){
        execute_external_command(cmd);
    }else{
        //execute_interal_command(cmd);
    }


}while(strcmp(cmd, "exit\n") != 0);

return 0;
}
```

And this is how my child process is replaced by the new process, a program called "hello". It just prints "Hello World" to the screen.

```
else{
    //Child process
    dup2(commpipe[0],0);
    close(commpipe[1]);

    //Replace child process with a new process
    if(execl("hello", "hello", NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error executing new process!\n");
        exit(3);
    } 
}
```

}

It works just fine. But I want to replace that "hello" with a variable like when I type "./hello" to get the "hello" part from there and use it as a variable in the execl() function.

I tried to do it like this, but it seems unable to find that "hello". I tried printing it on the screen and it prints "hello" like it should. Any ideas why the process is not executed ?

```
else{
    //Child process
    dup2(commpipe[0],0);
    close(commpipe[1]);

    char program[10];
    int len = strlen(cmd) - 2;
    memcpy(program, &cmd[2],len);

    //Replace child process with a new process
    if(execl(program, program, NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error executing new process!\n");
        exit(3);
    } 
}
```

}

Second question: In my first execution method it executed just fine with "hello" as a string in the execl() funcntion. I always print that "$ > " string o the screen, which is asking for an input. But when the child process finishes his execution, the whole program stops. How can I make him print that "$ > " string on the screen again for me to execute other commands if I want. Thanks in advance

UPDATE: Function that executes external commands

```
void execute_external_command(char cmd[]){

pid_t pid;
int rv;
int commpipe[2];

//Creting pipe
if(pipe(commpipe)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe!!\n");
    exit(1);
}

if((pid=fork()) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error forking ew process!\n");
    exit(2);
}

if(pid){
    //Parent process
    dup2(commpipe[1],1);
    close(commpipe[0]);
    setvbuf(stdout,(char*)NULL,_IONBF,0);
    wait(&rv);
    fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with a %d value", rv);
}else{
    //Child process
    dup2(commpipe[0],0);
    close(commpipe[1]);

    int len = strlen(cmd) - 2;
    char program[len];
    memcpy(program, &cmd[2],len);
    program[len-1] = '\0';

    //Replace child process with a new process
    if(execl(program, program, NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error executing new process!\n");
        exit(3);
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Does it print `Child exited with a %d value` before stopping?

Comment: regarding this line: `if(execl(program, program, NULL) == -1){`.  the `exec*()`  functions never return, unless an error occurs.  so the line should be: `execl(program, program, NULL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` includes the trailing newline in the string. You have to strip it in order to call the binary correctly. Furthermore, your memcpy does not copy the necessary zerobyte as string terminator. Try:

```
program[len-1] = '\0';
```

after the `memcpy()`.
That should help.

Another note: This code is prone to a buffer overflow, since program is fixed to 10 bytes, while cmd can be much longer.
You could do:

```
int len = strlen(cmd) - 2;
char program[len];
memcpy(program, &cmd[2],len);
program[len-1] = '\0';
```

to prevent this from happening. If you do not care about modifying cmd, you could also do:

```
cmd[strlen(cmd)-1] = '\0';

if (execl(cmd+2, cmd+2, NULL) ...
```

One more thing:

It is not even necessary to remove the `./`-part, execl will work just fine with it.

Here in the parent process:

```
if(pid){
    //Parent process
    dup2(commpipe[1],1);
```

you set stdout of your process to the commpipe. Thus, all subsequent printf's will try to write to a broken pipe, and hence a SIGPIPE terminates your parent process.
I do not see at all why you need the commpipe here, I think you can leave that out completely.

Comment: Well, that was simple. I forgot I used `fgets` there. Thank you very much. But can you help me with my second question too ? So that my program resumes asking for user input ?

Comment: @OlarAndrei does that help? If not, please provide some more code context

Comment: I've updated my code. This is how my entire function looks like. Can you tell me more precisely how to tell the parent that the child is done executing ? And how the program should go further displaying that "$ > " string from the beginning to get the user input and not to kill the program after the child is done executing ?

Comment: @OlarAndrei I see, I modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have a nice day. That worked.